# Use session variable or copy PHP code from second page to third page of a website

Tags: php, html, sql-server, session, session-variables

I have three pages in the website. The first is login page,second is profile page and third is main page.

```html
<?php
session_start();
$servername="blah blah blah";
$connectioninfo=array('Database'=>'mbr');
$conn=sqlsrv_connect($servername,$connectioninfo);
if($conn)
{
echo 'connection established';
}
else
{
echo 'connection failure';
die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),TRUE));
}

$q1="SELECT * FROM EmployeeTable WHERE EmployeeID = '" . $_SESSION['id'] . "' ";
$stmt=sqlsrv_query($conn,$q1);
if($stmt==false)
{
echo 'error to retrieve info !! <br/>';
die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),TRUE));
}
$row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);
echo $row['EmployeeName'];

$q2="SELECT * FROM pointsBadgeTable WHERE EmployeeID = '" . $_SESSION['id'] . "' ";
$stmt1=sqlsrv_query($conn,$q2);
if($stmt1==false)
{
echo 'error to retrieve info !! <br/>';
die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),TRUE));
}
$pbrow=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt1);
?>
```

The above is the php used in the second page of the website. Here I am using two queries $q1 and $q2 to retrieve information from two different tables (EmployeeTable and pointsBadgeTable) after connection to the database "mbr" here.

I then echo the desired Info in my html after retrieving info from the tables.

For instance,

```html
<?php echo "". $row['goldTotal'] .""?>>
```

Here 'goldtotal' is a column in the pointsBadgeTable in the above php. Also please note that I am using  " . $_SESSION['id'] ."  here to show info only about the person who logs in the first page of the website.

The issue here is that I want to echo the same value in the third page as in second page. Will I have to write the same php code in third page as I wrote in second page or I need to store it in some session variable. How to use a session variable here?

Also, is it correct to rewrite the same code in third page also as in second page and use the same queries $q1 and $q2? I will copy and paste the same PHP to the third page also.

Comment: Basically this question is opinion based. you can store the data in session if not too big and use in third page. but I would prefer to put your query and data fetching in a function/separate file and include/call it in both pages. the data may have changed when the user reaches the third page. Again lot depends on personal preference, and what you want to achieve.

Comment: @bansi thanks for the input.u basically mean to say that I can use the same php code ( as mentioned in above question) and use the same in third page also.That would mean that I would be connecting to the same server  and DB  again.

Answer (score 0):

You Can include the second page in third page , you will get the value .
Example : file3.php

```
**<?php 
include 'file2.php';
?>**
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.